# Add new perspective to existing Gui

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, plugins, view, perspective

So I have been working on a GUI with a single perspective with different views. But now we need another new perspective with different views. I have been going around online examples and tutorials on adding perspectives but did not find exactly what I was looking for.

The attached image shows my GUI. In the "Sample Menu" I want to have a menu item that will open my new perspective.

My attempt to solve it was to add another perspective alongside the original but nothing happened.
My next idea is to add the opening of the 2nd perspective as an action from the menu of the 1st perspective. But I don't know how to go about it or whether it is the correct approach at all. A snippet of the plug in is shown below.

[image: Perspective with different views]

```
  <perspective
        name="RCP Perspective"
        class="chipcoach.Perspective"
        id="ChipCoach.perspective">
  </perspective>

  <perspective
        class="chipcoach.Perspective2"
        id="ChipCoach.perspective2"
        name="PopupPerspective">
  </perspective>
```

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="ChipCoach.perspective">
  </perspectiveExtension>
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="ChipCoach.perspective2">
  </perspectiveExtension>
</extension>

   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
  <actionSet
        id="ChipCoach.actionSet"
        label="Sample Action Set"
        visible="true">
     <menu
           id="sampleMenu"
           label="Sample &amp;Menu">
        <separator
              name="sampleGroup">
        </separator>
     </menu>
     <action
           class="chipcoach.actions.SampleAction"
           icon="icons/sample.gif"
           id="chipcoach.actions.SampleAction"
           label="&amp;Sample Action"
           menubarPath="sampleMenu/sampleGroup"
           toolbarPath="sampleGroup"
           tooltip="Hello, Eclipse world">
     </action>
     <action
           class="chipcoach.actions.OpenPerspective1"
           icon="icons/sample.gif"
           id="chipcoach.actions.openPerspective1"
           label="&amp;Open Perspective"
           menubarPath="sampleMenu/sampleGroup"
           style="push"
           toolbarPath="sampleGroup">
     </action>
  </actionSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do need to add a menu item to open the new perspective. The code for this will be similar to the Eclipse `ShowPerspectiveHandler`:

```java
IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();

IWorkbenchWindow activeWorkbenchWindow = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

IWorkbenchPage activePage = activeWorkbenchWindow.getActivePage();

IPerspectiveDescriptor desc = workbench.getPerspectiveRegistry().findPerspectiveWithId(perspectiveId);

activePage.setPerspective(desc);
```

(Lots of error checks omitted for clarity)